# I went to change cell value from another cell in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2016, worksheet

I went to change the cell value from another cell in Excel.

For example:

If I write in `$a$1` number like 5 excel automatically set value for `$b$1` type phone and if I write in `$b$1` string like phone excel automatically set value for `$a$1` type 5.

[image: excel img example]

Comment: Perhaps this will be helpful [Worksheet.Change event (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change)

Comment: @NicholasHunter thanks for your response but I think my idea is wrong I can't change a cell from another cell by worksheet must VBA

Comment: @NicholasHunter I think I can type A1.Value  = "string" like programming I learn excel  because my College is accounting but I'm web designer

Comment: You will need to write a VBA macro